# module or software to preprocess simple variable substitution for JSON files?

Tags: text-processing, json, bash

I'm taking my vscode theme settings and I'm breaking it out into a full fledged theme.

Themes are in JSON format.

I would also like to create a more unified color scheme. Let's say I tell my theme to set syntax highlighting for builtin javascript functions to be blue. I have quite a few things I might make this shade of blue. Later on I might want to change that shade of blue, but it's a hassle to have to search through every instance in the theme and change it. It would be much better if I could simply write out some variables and then assign variables to the different parts of the JSON theme file.

I do this sort of thing all the time with scss preprocessors, but I'm not really sure how to do this with JSON.

Is there some kind of preprocessor I could use that would allow me basic variables in my JSON file and then once run, produced a new JSON file where all the variables values have been "rendered" out as a normal JSON File?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a great solution with this npm module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/variable-replacer

So for instance, I run the following command:

`variable-replacer ./source-enzo.json ../themes/enzo.json  --data=variables.json`

and it takes my source file, and replaces all the `%variables%` declared in my `variables.json` file.

And the variables in the variables.json file are simply:

```
 {
"variable": "key value"
}
```

Extremely easy set up!